# JavaScriptSerializer RecursionLimitExceed Exception

Tags: c#, json, serialization, ienumerable, javascriptserializer

I am using `JavaScriptSerializer` in my application to serialize the object and i encountered an exception while trying to serialize the collection from the data entity.

My code,

Getting the records from the database.

```
var data = new MadhuDBEntities().ords.ToList();
```

And I am serilizing the above data using `JavaScriptSerializer` as follow

```
JavaScriptSerializer jSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { RecursionLimit = 5 };
string json=jSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

And i am getting exception as follow[image: Recursion Limit Exceeded Exception]

I think because the record from the database contains additional values.

When serilaize the `data` without `RecursionLimit` I get the json data as follow,

`[{"OrderID":1,"EmployeeID":1,"CustomerID":"Madhu","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"ords","EntityContainerName":"MadhuDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"OrderID","Value":1}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"OrderID":2,"EmployeeID":1,"CustomerID":"Madhu","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"ords","EntityContainerName":"MadhuDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"OrderID","Value":2}],"IsTemporary":false}}]`

In the above actually only the OrderID,EmployeeID and CustomerID are the columns and other are added automatically and i think the problem is also due to them.

So Is there any way to serialize the `data` without the unnecessary terms.

Any idea to solve this, but i must use `JavaScriptSerializer` so tell solution using that..
[image: Data Variable]

Thanks in advance..

Comment: are you getting values in #data  ????

Comment: Yes getting a collection of type `ord` but it also includes that entity related items thats my problem, I need to remove those entity related items and keep only my data.

Comment: show that stuff what you are getting... in Data ????

Comment: @Aravind I have updated it in question pls see

Comment: Which data you want to remove ???

Comment: ok you are saying that you have a limit of 5 Data but in Data it comes 6 .. so you are getting problem ??? right

Comment: No I think you misunderstood the problem. I want to remove the entries added by Entity model in the collection.

Comment: oki you are saying that you want to remove _customerid .. _Orderid ,,... ???

Comment: s  you got it and also the `base[System.Data...]`..

Comment: That might be public variable ... change that to private variable so that you wont get it

Answer (score 0):

try like this

first you have to create class to deseralize the object like this you can use Online tool http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class EntityKeyValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class EntityKey
{
    public string EntitySetName { get; set; }
    public string EntityContainerName { get; set; }
    public List<EntityKeyValue> EntityKeyValues { get; set; }
    public bool IsTemporary { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
   [ScriptIgnore]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
   [ScriptIgnore]
    public int EntityState { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public EntityKey EntityKey { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
       System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ObjJSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();{ RecursionLimit = 2 };
```

To Serialize

```
            var ObjSerialize = ObjJSerializer.Serialize("JsonObject");
```

You can Use

```
       [ScriptIgnore]
```

this attribute to Ignore the object so that you wont get any exceptions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx

Comment: Actually I dont want serialization, i want to serialize the `data` collection without those unwanted data appended by entity.. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: try this attribute in that particular class [ScriptIgnore] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx

Comment: But if you want to serialize a Json string you have to declare a class to Serialize the Json Object !!

Comment: My piece of Code is Working I am not getting any exceptions and The Value comes correctly... Try with your data but dont forget to create a class

Comment: `MadhuDBEntities` class is not user-defined it is generated when creating the entity model so we cant add `[ScriptIgnore]` to its property.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your data to var data = new MadhuDBEntities().ords.Take(5).ToList() does that work?

i think it is because your query returns more than 5 results and you are specifically setting RecursionLimit to 5 in JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: Sorry I dont get it. Are you telling I should use `Take(5)`?

Comment: Either that or remove the  RecursionLimit = 5 from JavaScriptSerializer jSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { RecursionLimit = 5 }; You are returning 6 results, hence the error.

Comment: How? There is no relationship between the number of items in the collection and the `RecursionLimit`.Actually `RecursionLimit` is used to represent the level of object to be processed.Check this [RecursionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.recursionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I know how it works. Please just try removing the RecursionLimit from your serializer (it defaults to 100). It will resolve your problem...